# Rails application global definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I want to have some global variables

for example for the slack-notifier I wan to initilize It once and reusing it.

what are the best practices for something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $ sign to your variable and it become global. Like below :

```
$slack-notifier
```

Also it should initialize in `config/initializers` folder. For this You can create in any file under config/intializers like config/intializers/xyz.rb

If you don't want to change this throughout application. Then you can create a constant also.

As a convention you should create this constant in intializers folder.

```
config/intializers/initialize.rb
```

And contant inside it should be a capital word.

```
# config/intializers/initialize.rb

ANY_CONSTANT = 'xyz'
```

You can use this ANY_CONSTANT any where in app.

Comment: Hmm isn't there a way to define it in application.rb or environment.rb

Comment: You can create in any file under `config/intializers`  like `config/intializers/xyz.rb` You can also use proc lambda etc for conditional assignment as well.

Comment: You can also declare globals and constant in the `application.rb`, like inside a `config.after_initialize` block.

Comment: Yes, But we always create global variable for some specific module. So suggested should be to create a different file under `config/initializers` Also it will not affect any other initialization under `application.rb` file.

Answer (score 1):

In /config/initializers/global.rb

```
$slack-notifier
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Ruby on Rails 4.2 you have `config/secrets.yml` file, where you can store your settings.

You specify them like this:

```
your_app: &your_app
  app_id: 123
```

and get the values as follows:

```
Rails.application.secrets[:your_app]['app_id']
```

Another option is to have env variables. Take a look into [this gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv).

With dotenv you create a file called `.env` in the app's root directory and store your global settings there as follows:

```
APP_ID=123
```

To get it within app you would do

```
ENV['APP_ID']
```

Add this file to `.gitignore`. This is the most safe way to store app settings.